# How to load the layer style from PostgreSQL with Python

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, layers, style

I would like to write a Python macro that upon opening my QGIS project file will reload the default style for each layer from the PostgreSQL 'layer_style' table. I have had a look at the [documentation](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a0efa7999d115235eb94097930f0cab18) and can only work out how this is done from a SQLite db or .qml file.

Any pointers?

Comment: Matt, from QGIS 2.0, It will be possible to save layer styles in Postgresql\postgis database. I know it's not the same, but maybe it solves your need. Take a look here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zC-_AmmGTQ8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zC-_AmmGTQ8)

Comment: I have done that, I would like to know if it is possible to reload the default styles from the postgresql layer_style table using Python.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting the topic with QGIS 3.0 :). Looking at the `QgsVectorLayer` API documentation instead of `QgsMapLayer` API, you have the answer. You can use method [`saveStyleToDatabase`](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a740e7c805e866c54ee94f1c010b7b308)

There are related recipes to manipulate styles in PostgreSQL database from QGIS Python tests including `saveStyleToDatabase` case at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_provider_postgres.py#L1553